# Pull data from text box and update

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to pull data from a text box in a user form and use a calculation with it.

I am unsure on how to do this.

[This is currently how the user form looks.](http://gyazo.com/3f815e1bd2ac0cb00b0c52c34b759f56)

As you can see, when a user presses yes on the radio button, a number will appear under total cost. Same with when they select something from the combo box.

What I want to do is when a user enters a number (between a set range) it will calculate that number, multiplied by another number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear. can you please say  what is another number

Comment: Hello. What I want to do is, when a figure is entered into a text box, I want VBA to pick it up, multiply it by a figure depending on which button the user has clicked on the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub OptionButton2_Change()
    TextBox2.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text * 10
        End If
    ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text * 20
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Karthick, what I want is for the form to calculate a total through a user form. A user must enter 5 figures, select from a combo box what sort of paint they want, and whether they want an underoat. From here, the form will present them with a figure that will be the cost of the work.